# multiple selects with same value do this

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have diferent select options with the same values in a table.
how do i make that when all selects get the same value ("2") do something (add disabled atributte to an input)?

```
<table>
<td>
  <select class="class1">
    <option value="1">SI</option>
    <option value="2">NO</option>
  </select>
</td>

<td>
  <select class="class1">
    <option value="1">SI</option>
    <option value="2">NO</option>
  </select>
</td>

<td>
  <select class="class1">
    <option value="1">SI</option>
    <option value="2">NO</option>
  </select>
</td>

</table>

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="x">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows: Push the value of each select in an array and use [`unique()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/) to only keep unique values. In case you want to disable the input if the values of the selects are the same (either 1 or 2), disable the input if the length of this array is 1.

```js
$("select").on("change", function() {
  let a = [];
  $("select").each(function() {
    a.push($(this).val());
    $.unique(a);
  });
  if (a.length === 1) {
    $(".checkbox").attr("disabled", true);
  }
  else {
    $(".checkbox").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <td>
    <select class="class1">
      <option value="1">SI</option>
      <option value="2">NO</option>
    </select>
  </td>

  <td>
    <select class="class1">
      <option value="1">SI</option>
      <option value="2">NO</option>
    </select>
  </td>

  <td>
    <select class="class1">
      <option value="1">SI</option>
      <option value="2">NO</option>
    </select>
  </td>

</table>

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="x">
```

In case you only want to disable the input when the values of all selects are 2, you can do it as follows:

```js
$("select").on("change", function() {
  let a = [];
  $("select").each(function() {
    a.push($(this).val());
    $.unique(a);
  });
  if (a.length === 1 && $.inArray("2", a !== -1)) {
    $(".checkbox").attr("disabled", true);
  }
  else {
    $(".checkbox").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <td>
    <select class="class1">
      <option value="1">SI</option>
      <option value="2">NO</option>
    </select>
  </td>

  <td>
    <select class="class1">
      <option value="1">SI</option>
      <option value="2">NO</option>
    </select>
  </td>

  <td>
    <select class="class1">
      <option value="1">SI</option>
      <option value="2">NO</option>
    </select>
  </td>

</table>

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="x">
```

Comment: @francisco Glad that I was able to help. If this answered your question, please accept this answer to resolve your question as solved/answered.

Answer (score 1):

Read the values into an array `values`. If all of the values are 2 the disable the `checkbox` using `.prop('disabled', true)`:

```js
$('.class1').on('change', function() {
    let values = $('.class1').map(function() {
        return +this.value;
    }).get();
    values.some(checkValue) || $('#x').prop('disabled', true); 
});

function checkValue( value ) {
    return value !== 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <td>
    <select class="class1">
      <option value="1">SI</option>
      <option value="2">NO</option>
    </select>
  </td>

  <td>
    <select class="class1">
      <option value="1">SI</option>
      <option value="2">NO</option>
    </select>
  </td>

  <td>
    <select class="class1">
      <option value="1">SI</option>
      <option value="2">NO</option>
    </select>
  </td>

</table>

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="x">
```

Comment: thank u peter, but for some reason couldn´t make it work

Comment: You can compare your implementation with this working snippet to help you find out why it did not work.